# JavaScript firing custom event for Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can you give me an example for Chrome where I have something like this:

```
function checkVideoStatus(vidElement){
   var currentTime = vidElement.currentTime;
   //now wait 5 seconds
   var updatedTime = vidElement.currentTime;
   //now check if video has freezed
   if(updatedTime == currentTime){
      //fire videoFreeze Event
   }

}
```

So I would want to fire this event here. Also, is it really necessary to fire this event, since I already can put a relevant method call here to do what I want accordingly?

Is it in JS the events are only like `onChange`, `onMouseOver` etc?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide the relevant scenario in the question. See the [HTML5 video reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_av_dom.asp) to see, what you can do with such a video element. Maybe you just need to check `vidElement.paused`.

Comment: @maenu well i am using google webrtc for video stream from remote party however the API's are still under dev so they do not have call stopped event in native chrome yet, so i want to detect if remote video stream has stopped, then fire an event on some element (video element i guess), which user can handle as per their application logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple mockup of a custom event and a countdown.

```
<div id="vid" data-current="0">Video</div>​

var vid = document.getElementById('vid'),
    freeze;

vid.addEventListener('freeze', function() {
    console.log('Firing vid.freeze.... ' + this.dataset.current);
    console.log('vid.freeze fired.');
});

(function go() {
    var status;
    vid.innerHTML = 'Video time: ' + vid.dataset.current;

    if (vid.dataset.current < 5) {
        status = vid.dataset.current == 0 ? 'Starting... ' : 'Continuing... ';
        console.log(status + vid.dataset.current);
        setTimeout(go, 1000);
    } else {
        freeze = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        freeze.initEvent('freeze', true, true);
        vid.dispatchEvent(freeze);
    }

    vid.dataset.current++;
})();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Ampbm/1

This is mostly to show how to make a custom event which fires after five seconds. I'm also using the `data-` attribute to store the current time. What you're doing in the `if` block I'm not quite sure about, since `.updatedTime` and `.currentTime` seems to me to be possibly the same thing each go round.

Comment: Can you please edit your question (change at least 1 character), then the timeout mechanism resets and I can change my vote. I apologize about the situation.

Comment: I hacked the system - I edited it myself and as a result I could change my vote. Thanks for helping!