# How to listen and react on triggered CustomEvent?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, eventtrigger, dispatchevent, custom-events

I'd like to understand how the `CustomEvent` system works, in Javascript.

[EDIT2]

The **dream** solution is here : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/

[/EDIT2]

[EDIT]

This piece of codes illustrates pretty well the type of `DOM`-aware system I'm looking for, thx to @Jared Farrish, There is also the deferred method. *But I'm still thinking it is a kind of javascript limitation and that the langage deserves to implement a clever way to do. Ideally, children would not have to execute orders given by parent or by any other element. Instead, a child node should takes its own decisions, by knowing in real-time the interesting parts of DOM activity.*

```
var body = document.body,
    btn = document.getElementById('fire'),
    warn;

    warn = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    warn.initEvent('warning', true, true);

body.addEventListener('warning', function() {
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});

btn.addEventListener('warning', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function init() {
    body.dispatchEvent(warn);
    btn.dispatchEvent(warn);
});
```

*source : http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/2/*

[/EDIT]

Saying I create this very basic event :

```
var warning = new CustomEvent('warning', { 
    'detail': 'This is a warning!' 
});
```

Now the object `warning` contains useful data. It is stored in the browser memory. Let's trigger it.

```
document.dispatchEvent(warning);
```

By doing above statement, I think I say to `document` : "hey dude, fire this specific event plz". And then, the event is triggered. And how far as I understand, I assume it also means that (somehow) the `DOM` is aware that the event has been triggered.

Now I would like another element, saying body, to change is `style.backgroundColor` from transparent to red each time the event `warning` is triggered. In other word, I want body to listen to this specific event and react consequently.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('warning',
function(e){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}, false);
```

But this works not.

Actually, it works if I switch the position of `dispatchEvent()` and `addEventListener()`by initializing the second before the first. But it is not what I am expecting from Javascript. What I want to achieve is the ability to trigger an event somewhere, and ordering some element elsewhere  to catch it and react each time this event is triggered.

Is it something achievable?

*Note : I discovered promises today and thought they were what I'm looking for, but they're not as they just capable to "chain" things without being able to delay them.*

Comment: This is how you would organize it in a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/1 Note that the custom event is simply a vehicle for working the event through the DOM; it needs to be dispatched against the element, which is `document.body` in your example. Here's another (slightly more complete) example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12341715/451969

Comment: events are not remembered, so you have to add the listener before the event is raised...

Comment: Also, I think your confusion comes from the fact that you're creating and dispatching the event immediately (during page load, I assume), then (later in page load) adding a listener, which didn't exist when you called the custom event. This is a bit like calling "Wolf!" then buying sheep. Switching them around "works" because you're adding the event listener then immediately calling an event against it, so the order just happens to work. See in my example how I use an event handler on the `button.click` event, which means the event is created/dispatched after both events listeners exist.

Comment: Ty for your answers, @Jared Farrish I'm stil confused. In your first example, the background property is set by the init function, not because of the event. I might be wrong, but I'm looking for a system that make the button intelligent enough to "sniff" CustomEvents, detect (mostly alone) that "warning" has been triggered and adapt itself (by changing bkg color in this example).  Instead of only listening at DOM events, like  :  var body = document.body,
    btn = document.getElementById('fire');

btn.addEventListener('click', function init() {
    body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});

Comment: Put the desired effect (background color change) in the element's `warning` event handler? http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/2/

Comment: in other word, I want the click on a A button able to be detected by a B element, with nothing other link that the event itself (I would like to not have to write into the function something like "when click on A, change B". I want something like : "B, when A is clicked, change yourself"

Comment: I think what you want is a form of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). ([Also.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/451969))

Comment: About  event delegation, I definitely avoid jquery in my core mechanism, but this kinda ressource looks indeed very good http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20090209/127339.html

Comment: Here's a simple example of event delegation (no jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/5/

Comment: Here's a more complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/6/ And your request for a more "clever" method (ie, as it currently works is somehow limited) would result in a very slow and probably buggy architecture. There's a reason why it was constructed like it is. The "alternative" that some use is to attach an event handler to the `document` node itself, which means the `document` processes all events that bubble or propagate to it. Note, `document.body` event delegation in most cases should be avoided at all costs (due to inefficiency, look up `jQuery.live()` for more info).

Comment: This is an example of using `document` to listen to an event: http://jsfiddle.net/p6myjLza/7/ (Note how similar it is to the previous, `parent` example.)

Comment: Forget about it ;) Thx for all the examples, it helps a lot!

Comment: People new to Javascript always complain about how it's different; learn it first, use it, and when you've mastered it, then complain about it. It's much more powerful than it looks at first. (And I think what you're reaching for are [observables/binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), which are not low-level in Javascript (yet).)

Comment: And of course [`Object.observe()`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/).

Comment: Yes!!! that is exactly what I think we need to develop intelligent UI! u_u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it! What happens, however, is that you are triggering the event on the `document` level and the `body` tag, where the event handler is, is lower - events bubble up when triggered.

If you simply dispatch the event from the `body`, you'd see it triggers the handler

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].dispatchEvent(warning);
```